# Where to store Group Policy Software Installation packages?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I am starting to distribute some software packages via Group Policy but I am wondering where the best place to store the software installation packages is.

I have seen online but I wanted to double check, is it safe to store software installation packages in `\\domain.local\SYSVOL\domain.local` and point the Group Policy Software Installation to this path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The software packages should be stored on the domain controllers (as you've found during your research). This way you enable their distribution over all DC in your domain, which means swift installation for workstations in different sites.

You can consider creating a network share on the domain controller(s), which must have read access for all users in your domain (if certain logon scripts need to be executed for the users, and also to allow successful installation of different packages - some softwares can get installed without administrator account, because they get installed in the user's directory). In that network share you can create a folder structure which will allow you to keep different versions of every software you deploy with policy, allowing you to revert to previous version if an issue occurs.